# JavaScript Faster way to ask for null value

Tags: javascript

I have a question. I created the following functions:

```
function checkGender(canidate, callback) {

    var query = "SELECT a.* FROM (SELECT Id AS GebruikerId, TIMESTAMPDIFF(year, profiel_Geboortedatum, NOW()) AS Leeftijd FROM " + 
    "gebruikers WHERE Id = " + canidate.MedereizigerId + ") a INNER JOIN gebruikers ON gebruikers.Id = " + canidate.GebruikerId + " WHERE a.Leeftijd >= gebruikers.medereiziger_MinLeeftijd AND " + 
    "a.Leeftijd <= gebruikers.medereiziger_MaxLeeftijd GROUP BY a.GebruikerId;";
    
    FYSCloud.API.queryDatabase(query).done(function (data) {
    
        if (data.length == 1) {
            callback(data);
        }
        else {
            callback(null);
        }
    
    }).fail(function (reason) {
        console.log(reason);
        callback(null);
    });
}



function checkAge(canidate, callback) {

    var query = "SELECT a.* FROM (SELECT Id AS GebruikerId, TIMESTAMPDIFF(year, profiel_Geboortedatum, NOW()) AS Leeftijd FROM " + 
    "gebruikers WHERE Id = " + canidate.MedereizigerId + ") a INNER JOIN gebruikers ON gebruikers.Id = " + canidate.GebruikerId + " WHERE a.Leeftijd >= gebruikers.medereiziger_MinLeeftijd AND " + 
    "a.Leeftijd <= gebruikers.medereiziger_MaxLeeftijd GROUP BY a.GebruikerId;";
    
    FYSCloud.API.queryDatabase(query).done(function (data) {
    
        if (data.length == 1) {
            callback(data);
        }
        else {
            callback(null);
        }
    
    }).fail(function (reason) {
        console.log(reason);
        callback(null);
    });
}

[...]
```

Now the queries are working like a charm but I am using the following code to call these functions:

```
for(var i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
        
    // CHECK GESLACHT
    checkGender(data[i], function(genderData) {
        if(genderData != null) {
            
            // CHECK LEEFTIJD
            checkAge(data[i], function(ageData) {
                if(ageData != null) {
                
                    // CHECK BUDGET
                    checkBudget(data[i], function(budgetData) {
                        if(budgetData != null) {
            
                            // CHECK VAKANTIELAND
                            checkDestinationCountries(data[i], function(destinationCountryData) {
                                if(destinationCountryData != null) {
                
                                    // CHECK GESPROKEN TALEN
                                    checkSpokenLanguages(data[i], function(spokenLanguagesData) {
                                        if(spokenLanguagesData != null) {
                                            
                                        }
                                    });
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        }
    });
}
```

What I am doing here is waiting for the function to finish and then continue with the next one, but only if the result of the function didn't return `null`. Now this takes up a lot of lines and tabs, so I was wondering if there was a beter way to ask everytime for a null value?

Please let me know, just out of curiosity

Comment: There's a common mistake in your code. You're using `var i` in your loop, and the code inside it is using `i` asynchronously. Inside the callbacks, for every single iteration, the value of `i` will be `data.length`, because the loop will have finished, and the callbacks will all still be running, but with the final value of `i`. You need to isolate the scope of `i` to each iteration by using `let i` instead of `var i`

Comment: Thank you @blex! Could you look at the comment on the answer below, because I don't understand someting about his answer. Maybe you know the answer?

Comment: Using Promises would make your code much more readable, with a lot less indentations (what you have here is called ["callback hell"](https://www.google.com/search?q=callback+hell)). What library are you using to make DB queries?

Comment: My College has an API that I need to use, I can't see the code behind it.... Very lame :(

Comment: `checkGender` and `checkAge` do exactly the same thing, why the need to call it twice with different names? (this is important because the recommended way here would be to rewrite these functions so that you have a single `queryDB(type, candidate)` that could indeed return a Promise.)

Comment: I still need to make the sql for checkGender, so its for now a copy paste. Do you know the answer for the problem of me on the anser below? In the comments! Then I can finish this question and go on with coding :)

Comment: Yes, you need to learn how to use arrow functions. (wrap your code in `{}`, so `(foo)=>{dosomething(); dosomethongElse(); return the_result;}`).

Comment: Then it says: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '.'`. Thats the dot for `console.log("IT WORKS!!!");`. Why does it give an error on that???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change your function to a [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) based result, instead of calling callbacks use resolve and reject, like this:

```js
function checkAge(canidate) {

    // create a new Promise and return it
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        var query = "SELECT a.* FROM (SELECT Id AS GebruikerId, TIMESTAMPDIFF(year, profiel_Geboortedatum, NOW()) AS Leeftijd FROM " + 
        "gebruikers WHERE Id = " + canidate.MedereizigerId + ") a INNER JOIN gebruikers ON gebruikers.Id = " + canidate.GebruikerId + " WHERE a.Leeftijd >= gebruikers.medereiziger_MinLeeftijd AND " + 
        "a.Leeftijd <= gebruikers.medereiziger_MaxLeeftijd GROUP BY a.GebruikerId;";
        
        FYSCloud.API.queryDatabase(query).done(function (data) {
            if (data.length == 1) {
                resolve(data); // when successful, resolve with data
            }
            else {
                reject('no data found'); // any error, call reject()
            }
        
        }).fail(function (reason) {
            console.log(reason);
            reject(reason); // any error, call reject()
        });
    });
}
```

With this, you can use async/await feature to write a generic validation method with all others validation functions, because any call to reject will throw a exception:

```
async function checkData(data) {
    try {
        const genderData = await checkGender(data);
        const ageData = await checkAge(data);
        const budgetData = await checkBudget(data);
        const destinationCountryData = await checkDestinationCountries(data);
    } catch (e) {
        // some validation failed
    }
}
```

Comment: I still need to use the data that the check functions return!?

Comment: sorry, I completely forgot this... I edit the question, you can use the promise result, the `resolve` method will return the value passed to it

Comment: And I want the checkData function to return a string that has been build up in the try after the awaits. Now when I do the following in a different function: `var matchHTML = checkData(data[i]);` and print matchHTML, it says: `[object Promise]`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @A.Vreeswijk Here are some example usages of the code above: https://pastebin.com/embed_iframe/aDbwYD8U (assuming you `return` the HTML in the `try`, and `return null;` in the `catch`)

Comment: I need to add matchHTML to an existing string variable using concat, but when I do: `checkData(data[i]).then(returnValue => matchHTML = matchHTML.concat(returnValue));` It doesn't get added !?

Comment: If you used the "fire & forget" method, it will be added eventually, but you have no way of knowing when. I think the last method (`Promise.all()`) would suit your needs

Comment: Where do I need to put that? In checkData?

Comment: Outside of `checkData`. In place of your `for` loop. You'll get an Array containing all the strings, some of them being `null` if candidates did not meet all the requirements. You can then filter that array and concatenate it: `var matchHTMLForAllCandidates = matchHTMLs.filter(s => s !== null).join('');`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225693/discussion-between-a-vreeswijk-and-blex).

Comment: Very clean, nice solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `&&` operator to check for a falsy value (null, 0, false, undefined, etc.) before executing a function.

`value && functionCall(value)`

That might make it a bit cleaner.

```
checkGender(data[i], genderData => genderData &&
    checkAge(data[i], ageData => ageData &&
        checkBudget(data[i], budgetData => budgetData &&
            checkDestinationCountries(data[i], destinationCountryData => destinationCountryData &&
                checkSpokenLanguages(data[i], spokenLanguagesData => spokenLanguagesData && console.log("It Works"))))))
```

Comment: Why is `genderData` between () and `ageData` not, then `budgetData` again?

Comment: @A.Vreeswijk There's no reason for it, if an arrow function only accepts 1 parameter, the parentheses are optional

Comment: And how can I start coding inside the functions, because I now have the following on the last line: `checkSpokenLanguages(data[i], spokenLanguagesData => spokenLanguagesData && console.log("IT WORKS!!!"); )))));`

But that gives me the error: `Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list`

Comment: Added that to the code. Don't put a `;` after `console.log` for an arrow function. If you need a body, then you have to add `{ }` after the `=>`.

Comment: Sorry, you don't need the `()` around the parameters. That's optional.